# Flutter | Why does my json file is transformed into a folder on firebase when I try to access it?

Tags: json, flutter, firebase-storage

When I try to access my json file from my emulator using a url and a http post request in firebase storage, it transorm into a folder, and when I print data, it gives me the data of the folder not the file.
**Code:**

```
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _store = Firestore.instance;
  String khatma;
  String link;
  var data;

  down_data() async {
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    await _store.collection('users').document(user.uid).get().then(
          (value) => {
            setState(
              () {
                khatma = value.data['Joined'];
              },
            ),
          },
        );
  }

  Future getAya() async {
    await down_data();
    if (khatma == 'Khatma 1') {
      var response = await http.post(
        'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/khatma-project.appspot.com/o/Ayat%2Fsurah_1.json?alt=media&token=6bc1994b-6896-4541-a20c-687cbe6e6208',
      );
      data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      print(data);
    } else if (khatma == 'Khatma 2') {
      setState(() {});
    } else if (khatma == 'Khatma 3') {
      setState(() {});
    } else if (khatma == 'Khatma 4') {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    getAya();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: You can simply upload a new file to replace the one you want to change.

Comment: from inside the app from diffrent users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if I nested the Verse_num to name and taken boolean like this:

```
"Surah_1": {
    "verse_1": {
 "name": "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
 "taken": "true if taken, flase if not"
       },
}
```